# Can't pass variable to jwplayer url?

Tags: jquery, youtube, jwplayer

I want to get the first element from a list of youtube urls and play it in a container using jwplayer.

For some reason I'm getting a cross domain policy restriction error when I pass the url in with via variable, but it works fine when I put the url in directly.

Any suggestions?  Here is the javascript I'm using that gets the error:

```
function getTopLink() {
    var addressValue = $('.list_container li:first-child .youtube').attr("href");
    alert(addressValue);
    return addressValue;
    }

  var stage = getTopLink();

  jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({
    'flashplayer': '/jwplayer/player.swf',
    'id': 'playerID',
    'width': '640',
    'height': '380',
     icons: false,
    'skin': '/skins/grungetape.zip'
  });

  jwplayer().load(stage);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there is a much more efficient way to do this, but this is what I came up with that seems to work:

```
function getTopLink() {
  var addressValue = $('.list_container li:first-child .youtube').attr("href");
  return addressValue;
  }
var x = getTopLink();

function replaceToWatch(i,stage) {  
  var stage = x;
  var newStage = stage.replace(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:embed\?v=|embed)(\/)?(.+)/g, 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$2');
  return newStage;

}

var topVideo = replaceToWatch();

jwplayer('playerContainer').setup({
  'flashplayer': '/jwplayer/player.swf',
  'id': 'playerID',
  'width': '640',
  'height': '380',
   icons: false,
  'file': topVideo,
  'skin': '/skins/grungetape.zip'
});
```